# Evolution CMS FormLister — Не удалось отправить письмо

Tags: modx, evolution

Всем доброго дня!
Пытаюсь обновить Evolution c 1.4.0 R2 до 1.4.3
В eform после обновления не работает капча.
После перехода на FormLister после отправки выдается сообщение — Не удалось отправить письмо.

```
    [!FormLister?
&formid=`ContactForm`
&to=`info@daodemei.com`
&subject=`Отзыв с сайта`
&config=`default:core`
&isHtml=`0`
&protectSubmit=`1`
&rules=`{
"name":{
    "required":"Обязательно введите Имя"
},
"email":{
    "required":"Обязательно введите Email",
    "email":"Введите Email правильно"
},
"phone":{
    "required":"Обязательно введите Номер телефона",
    "phone":"Введите Номер телефона правильно"
},
"message":{
    "required":"Обязательно введите Сообщение",
    "minLength":{
        "params":5,
        "message":"Сообщение должно быть не менее 5 символов"
    }
}
}`

&allowedFields=`name,email,phone,subject,message`
&messagesTpl=`@CODE:<div><ul>[+required+][+errors+][+messages+]</ul></div>`
&messagesOuterTpl=`@CODE:<li>[+messages+]</li>`
&messagesRequiredOuterTpl=`@CODE:<li>[+messages+]</li>`
&messagesErrorOuterTpl=`@CODE:<li>[+messages+]</li>`
&messagesSplitter=`</li><li>`
&messagesRequiredSplitter=`</li><li>`
&messagesErrorSplitter=`</li><li>`
&errorClass=`error`
&requiredClass=`required`
&captcha=`modxCaptcha`
&captchaParams=`{
    "width":"148",
    "height":"60",
    "errorEmptyCode":"Код Captcha отсутствует",
    "errorCodeFailed":"Код Captcha не правильный"
}`

&captchaField=`captchacode`
&formTpl=`@CODE:
<div class="form_messages">                                                                 
        [+form.messages+]
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <div class="contacts">
<form class="form-horizontal" action="[~[*id*]~]#contact_form" method="post"  id="contact_form">
  <input type="hidden" name="formid" value="ContactForm">
          <div class="form-group[+name.errorClass+][+name.requiredClass+]">
                    <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">* Имя</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Имя" name="name" value="[+name.value+]">
                    <!--    [+name.error+] -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group[+email.errorClass+][+email.requiredClass+]">
                    <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">* Email</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" value="[+email.value+]">
                  <!--      [+email.error+] -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group[+phone.errorClass+][+phone.requiredClass+]">
                    <label for="phone" class="col-sm-2 control-label">* Телефон</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="+7915 123 45 67" name="phone" value="[+phone.value+]">
                    <!--    [+phone.error+] -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group[+message.errorClass+][+message.requiredClass+]">
                    <label for="message" class="col-sm-2 control-label">* Сообщение</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="message" placeholder="Ваше сообщение" name="message" rows="10">[+message.value+]</textarea>
                   <!--     [+message.error+] -->
                    </div>
                </div>

  <!-- modxCaptcha -->
  <div class="[+captchacode.errorClass+][+captchacode.requiredClass+]">
    <label for="captchacode" class="compulsory">Код captcha:</label>
    <img src="[+captcha+]" alt="Captcha Image"><br>
    <br>
    Введите код captcha :
    <input type="text" name="captchacode" id="captchacode" value="">

  </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2" style="margin-top: 20px; width: 440px;">
         <input type="submit" value="Отправить" class="submit_button" />
    </div>

</form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>`
&successTpl=`@CODE:<div>Спасибо, мы свяжемся с вами как можно скорее.</div>`
&reportTpl=`@CODE:
<p>Имя: [+name.value+]</p>
<p>Телефон: [+phone.value+]</p>
<p>Email: <a href="mailto:[+email.value+]">[+email.value+]</a></p>
<p>Сообщение: [+message:strip_tags:nl2br+]</p>
`
!]
```

В событиях появляется ошибка
SMTP connect() failed. github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Comment: в ошибке то все указанно - не может приконнектится к SMTP. Проверьте конфиги подключения к почтовому серверу

Comment: Taarim спасибо за ответ. Как в modx проверить какие smtp параметры используются. В настройках modx параметры smtp те же самые.